# Access database sharing strategies

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, collaboration, sharing

What are the strategies you employ to let multiple people work on an access database?

Is it possible to host it online and have its features still functional without having to develop a custom frontend?

MS Access as a software has a few nice features that don't require any programming to configure:

- Drop down lists - choose one
- Multi Checkbox lists - choose multiple

Is it possible to get all of these features available even when hosted online? I'm basically thinking of an alternate way to quickly get people to work with data using GUI features like the above without going the webapp<>MySQL way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way i've heard of, is to import the access database into a SQL Server database.
(Almost any version will do.).

Then link to the SQL Server database with Access and let users use it as they did before.

Look at this link: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA010345991033.aspx

If you want an online solution i'd recommend going with a normal web application architecture. (Talking to a proper database.).

Comment: Based on your last paragraph, you seem to consider your first three paragraphs as answering the "how to let multiple users use it" part of the question, which is complete BS -- upsizing the back end to SQL Server certainly allows you to support extremely large user populations, but it's not at all necessary just to allow multiple users. A Jet/ACE back end by default easily supports small workgroups on the order of 15-25 users. Anything above that requires increasing degress of special care, and it's at those user populations that I'd encourage a client to upsize. Below that, not so much.

Answer (score 5):

You have some good comments here. Keep in mind that things have changed quite a bit for access 2010.

Access 2010 allows you to build web applications. The development process is very much the same as it’s been for years, but you can’t use VBA in forms for these web applications (you use a new macro language).  This new feature set allows you to publish applications you build to a website. Here is an video of an application of mine running in access 2010, and at the halfway point in the video I switch to running the access application 100% in a web browser:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

The above is for access 2010…due out this year. The above will require you to be running SharePoint services, or use an hosting service that supports "access web" services.

For previous versions of access, for all intents and purposes, it’s not a web based system at all. Now when you say multiple users, you have to clarify what kind of users and where they plan to be. If your users are on a local office network, then MS access can be used as a multi user system right out of a box with no additional coding and programming required. It is recommended however that you split your application into a front end part that’s deployed on each user’s computer. This Concept as outlined in the following article of mine.

http://www.members.shaw.ca/AlbertKallal/Articles/split/index.htm

Now, perhaps the users are going to be on notebooks and in different locations all over the country? In this type of case you are attempting to connect over a wide area network, or have users connect to the application over the Internet. This is a different problem.  In this type of scenario, a good solution is to use something like SQL server for the backend, and you continue to deploy the Access front ends to each user’s computer.  This application tends to be about the most cost affordable also. And using sql server + ms-access means you get to continue developing in Access for the most part like you always done. Another way to accomplish wide area use without resorting to sql server is to use something called terminal services. I outline these possibilities in the following article:

http://www.members.shaw.ca/AlbertKallal//Wan/Wans.html

As mentioned, a few others here posted links to some of the new SharePoint features that you can consider using, but they not out untill later this year.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-user Access apps are pretty easy to do for small workgroup user populations in the 15-25 ranger or smaller. Above that, a developer should consider upsizing to a server back end, with the trade-off being greater administrative overhead for the server vs. having to program the app more carefully if you retain the Jet/ACE back end.

As to online access, you this isn't possible over HTTP, but if you have a Windows Terminal Server available, you can host your app there and give users access to that. This is actually an extremely easy and efficient and inexpensive way to support remote users of an app, though the larger the user population, the more problematic it becomes. But by the time an Access app has a user population that would strain a Windows Terminal Server setup, you're no longer going to be using a Jet/ACE back end.

And with a server back end, you could give access to a SQL Server on a VPN over the Internet, and if you write your Access app really efficiently, even over a standard broadband connection, your users could still work productively.

Then there's the future of Access: in Access 2010, a great deal of work has been done to integrate with a host of new features in Sharepoint 2010. If you create your A2010 app using the new type of Access web forms and reports, your app can be uploaded to a Sharepoint server running the new Access Services, and it can then be used running in a web browser (not limited to IE and not dependent on any plugins or web controls, as was the case in the past with the completely worthless Access Data Access Pages). The data store can either be a SQL Server, or you could keep it Jet/ACE for users not accessing it via the web browser, and have the data stored in Sharepoint for the online users. Also, you can have an app integrated with Sharepoint running locally in Access that uses Sharepoint when connected to the Internet, and still be able to work offline when disconnected. When connected again, you synch your local changes with the Sharepoint server, resolve any differences and continue working.

The features are really quite remarkable, and according to what I've heard and seen, if the Access app is built entirely of web forms and reports, it will look and function identically when run in Access and when run in the web browser via Sharepoint. And if you need to have client-side features that you don't expose to the users running the app in the browser, you can still use traditional Access objects!

The [Access development team's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/access/default.aspx) has a number of posts on what's coming in A2010, and there's [a good video posted there demonstrating how A2010 integrates with Sharepoint 2010's new Access Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/access/archive/2009/12/02/the-access-show-managing-access-databases-with-sharepoint.aspx).

This constitutes a quantum leap in Access's web capabilities, which were previously almost non-existent, and I'm quite excited about this. I was formerly quite wary of the changes being made to Access that seemed entirely to make it a servant of Sharepoint, but now I can see that the benefit to Access users and Access developers will be huge.

Answer (score 0):

I have never needed to support it myself, but from what I heard so far, performance dramatically breaks down as soon as you need to support multiple users writing simultaneously. I think this is because Access uses simple file locking to implement isolation, and this just is not the right technique for a concurrent database system.

Comment: Your comment is only true if you've designed your app badly.

Comment: David, can you give an example of what is bad and what is good in this context?

Answer (score -2):

Hosted on-line?  Do you mean on the network?  Technically it will work on a network but there is a reason MS-Access in not in Visual Studio - it is not considered a development platform - it is a desktop application.  When MS-Access first hit the scene many people built applications using it.  The multiuser functionality just is not there.  Upto four or five users is ok.  But I would not go for more.

Comment: "it is not considered a development platform" -- by whom? Access is certainly a development platform -- that's indisputable. A lot of ignorant people may not know that or look down their arrogant noses at Access, but who pays much attention to the ignorant and the arrogant?

Comment: You might not go for more than 4-5 users, but that's because you obviously don't know how to use Access as a development tool -- 15-25 users in a workgroup is a very standard user population for Access apps built by competent developers. Above that, upsizing of the back end is probably advisable since otherwise you have to work harder architecting your application. And, of course, this applies only to an Access app with a Jet/ACE back end.

Comment: Also, you're obviously completely confused about the distinction between Access and the Jet/ACE database engine (Access's default db engine) -- with a server back end, you can support literally 1000s of users from an Access front end.

Comment: @David - I have obviously offended you but we here at SO are supposed to try and be nice to each other. You obviously know more than I do about MS-Access. That's why SO is so great - a wide varity of expertice and opinions. Jeremy should greatly appreciate your input. He is certainly free to ignore mine.

Comment: @David - I may be dating myself here but, years ago I lost count of the number of failed multiuser MS-Access applications created by a fortune 50 company I did work for (none of which I worked on). By the passion of your comments perhaps that history remains in peoples mind. Because of those falures, I know a lot of developers that would not consider MS-Access seriously for a file-server based multiuser system beyond 4-5 users. I assumed by "on-line" and "not the MySql way" this is what Jeremy had in mind. If not, Sharepoint with an SQL database sounds worth considering.

Comment: @David - I remember when MS-Access and FoxPro were marketed as part of Microsoft's development suite of products.  This was before the first Visual Studio in 1997.  Visual Studio .NET (2002) is when FoxPro was dropped.  MS-Access was dropped before that.  My recollection is that we considered that a signal from Microsoft to look elsewhere for serious database development.

Comment: Development with Access should be done by an Access developer. You wouldn't criticize .NET as a development platform if a non-developer were somehow able to produce a really badly-designed .NET app, would you? So why badmouth Access? The "problem" with Access is that it makes it TOO EASY to create apps, and, thus, a lot of non-developers end up producing really bad apps. This is not a BUG but a FEATURE of Access, much like the loose design of HTML allows the production of hideously badly-structured pages that still just work.

Comment: The fact that "a lot of [non-Access] developers" would not use Access for more than 4-5 users says more about "a lot of developers" than it does about Access. Those are people who obviously don't know enough about Access to be judging appropriate user populations for an Access app, so it's probably good that those developers wouldn't try to use Access. The sad part is thea they then blather on to others with an air of unearned authority about how nobody else should use Access for developing database apps for those user populations. AND THEY ARE WRONG.

Comment: Marketinging often doesn't understand the products it promotes. Access is unclassifiable as only end-user or development tool -- it is both. This confuses an awful lot of otherwise intelligent people. And taking your signals from Microsoft without evaluating whether MS knows what it's talking about is dangerous -- for example, the ADO-in-Access debacle of A2000, where those of us who understood the issue ignored ADO for Access/Jet development, and 2 versions later were vindicated when MS abandoned its promotion of ADO for Jet data in Access. This has happened before and it will happen again.

Comment: @David – Your frustration is obvious and perhaps warranted but please try to be nice to people here on SO. Your points are well taken, but I have to look past the name calling to see them.

Comment: What name calling are you talking about?