# Sharing control to maintain Access database on One-Drive

Tags: ms-access, onedrive

We have a central Access database (with smaller peripheral databases attached) that we would like several users not in the same locality to work on through a network. We currently have the databases on OneDrive; we would also like to lock the database when it is being edited.

I see there is a relevant post that is 5 years old on StackOverflow:
[Access database sharing strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031486/access-database-sharing-strategies)

We have the Office 365 version. Would the solution enable us to lock the databases when they are in use? Are there new solutions to help with our task? We are also willing to try other online storage options if they are better than OneDrive.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post you provide a link to is quote old now, and some of what it says is bang on still, but some of it is a little bit misleading.

Running an access file that is stored on OneDrive sounds like a very bad idea to me.

The post mentioned "Windows Terminal Server".  This is a good solution as in effect it allows multiple users to open their own copy of an access file that grabs data from a single Access database file stored on the machine they are accessing using WTS.  You will need to investigate this more.

That said, I've never used the above.

I wanted to write as you should be aware that Access 2013 can be used with SQL Server to store it data.  Some "slightly more expensive subscriptions designed for business" will give the subscribers access to Sharepoint and Access 2013 can then be used to create "Access web apps", and Access makes it really easy to store the data on a SQLServer that is managed for you and really simple to use.   Users can also enter and view data into what MS calls "Access Views" which are essentially basic Access forms that can be used in a web browser.

My gut feeling is that the WTS route will be best for you.

It's worth noting that there can be considerable work to move data from an Access file into SQLServer using the MS tools.  This depends on what features of Access you use.

Comment: Thank you Harvey for your advice, the age of the post is something that I was really worried about and your opinion was very helpful. I will discuss with my supervisor about WTS.

Comment: It's worth noting that there can be considerable work to move data from an access file into SQL server using the MS tools.  This depends on what features of access you use.   (Also, I found the WROX book "Access 2013 Programming" very useful as it is mainly about using Access with web apps and SQL Server.